# How to create alphabetic sections in TableView with header from MutableArray using swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, swift3

I'm trying to add sections to my table but I can't manage to get my fist letter from my `MutableArray` (my `database` that contain 60 values) into a `dictionary`.
I want to create alphabetic `sections` with the first letter as the header and the number of rows in sections as all the values that start with that letter.

my code:

```
func getSectionsFromData() -> Dictionary<Character,String> {

    var sectionDictionary = Dictionary<Character, String>()

    let crime: CrimesInfo = marrCrimesNames.object(at: 0) as! CrimesInfo
    var crimeFirstLetter: AnyObject
    let crimeName = crime.Name

    for crime in marrCrimesNames {
        crimeFirstLetter = crimeName.characters.first! as AnyObject
        print(crimeFirstLetter)
    }
    return sectionDictionary
}
```

Output:

"A" // 60 times

Comment: For a TableView that is sorted, it may be more interesting to have the following structure (in pseudo code): `myDataArray = [{"A":[item1, item2], "B":[item4, item5, item6]...}]`, and for the count, you just have to get `(myDataArray[indexPath.section] as array).count` ?

Comment: I know this way and I'm sure it going to work but I have 60 values seems like unnecessary work if I can get it from my MutableArray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
for crime in marrCrimesNames {
    crimeFirstLetter = crimeName.characters.first! as AnyObject
    print(crimeFirstLetter)
}
```

You're not actually using the `crime` variable
Instead you're using only `crimeName` that's why you're getting "A" all the time.

Try instead

```
for crime in marrCrimesNames {
    crimeFirstLetter = crime.Name.characters.first! as AnyObject
    print(crimeFirstLetter)
}
```

Now to create a dictionary like this:

```
let dict = ["A" : ["Aname1", "Aname2", "Aname3"], "B" : ["Bname1", "Bname2", "Bname3"]]
```

from an array like this:

```
let array = ["Aname1", "Aname2", "Aname3", "Bname1", "Bname2", "Bname3"]
```

You can use this code:

```
let dict = ["A" : ["Aname1", "Aname2", "Aname3"], "B" : ["Bname1", "Bname2", "Bname3"]]

let characters = Array(Set(array.flatMap({ $0.characters.first })))

var result = [String: [String]]()

for character in characters.map({ String($0) }) {
    result[character] = array.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(character) })
}

print(result) // output: ["B": ["Bname1", "Bname2", "Bname3"], "A": ["Aname1", "Aname2", "Aname3"]]
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked! Now I need to get all the values into the dictionary and match them with the word that start with the same letter. Can you help me with that?

Comment: what exactly do you need? to create a dict like this?
`let dict = ["A" : ["Aname1", "Aname2", "Aname3"], "B" : ["Bname1", "Bname2", "Bname3"]]`

Comment: Yes just like you said but I need it to be from my MutableArray.  e.g.: MutableArray = [Aname1, Aname2, Bname1, Bname2, Cname] I need to store it in let dict